# Accordion text effect is not working in a simple html page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, accordion

I'm trying to implement this [simple text accordion effect](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol) but it's not working...I can't find why...If I create a simple html page with the same code (copy & paste) it's working but if I try to implement this accordion effect to another html page with previous content (a simple html menu and some JavaScript variables), when I click on the button...nothing changes!! So...the effect is not working...and I can't find the reason.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordion.css" type="text/css" media="screen">


<script>

var textRecovered = localStorage.getItem("storedText");
var lines = textRecovered.split("\n");
window.localStorage.clear();
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    console.log(lines[i]);
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (var j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
    acc[j].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="mainArea"> 
            <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
            <div class="panelacc">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>

            <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
            <div class="panelacc">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>

            <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
            <div id="foo" class="panelacc">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!-- MENU -->
    <div class="container">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/t1.png" /> Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/t2.png" />Reporting</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="llog.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />LYNIS LOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />LYNIS REPORT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/t3.png" />Lynis Tests</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Accounting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Authentication</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Banner</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Boot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Crypto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />File Integrity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Firewall</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Hardening</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Kernel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Logging</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Mail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Malware</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Nameservers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Networking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />PHP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Printing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Processes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Shell</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Software</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Squid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />SSH</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Storage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Time</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Tooling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Web</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/t2.png" />Overview</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END MENU -->
</body>
</html>
```

menu.css, accordion.css and layout.css (all together):

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color:#bababa;
    color:#fff;
}

div#fileOutput{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type="file"]{
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;

}


div#mainArea{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}
#nav {
    border:3px solid #3e4547;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 8px #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color:#d4d5d8;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8 url("../images/down.gif") no-repeat;
}
#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav li a img {
    border-width:0px;
    height:24px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin-right:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:24px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#bcbdc1;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    background: url("../images/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background:url("../images/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav a.sub:focus {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
    display:block;
}
#nav a.sub:active {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:active ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;
}
#nav ul:hover li {
    margin-top:0;
}

button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796";
}

div.panelacc {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panelacc.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Man, i'm getting a script error on 
var textRecovered = localStorage.getItem("storedText");
var lines = textRecovered.split("\n");
localStorage doest not contain storedText

Comment: try to narrow this down as much as possible, posting your entire page is not going to be very encouraging to many of us trying to debug your code...

Comment: you can ignore this part: `var textRecovered = localStorage.getItem("storedText");
var lines = textRecovered.split("\n");
window.localStorage.clear();
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    console.log(lines[i]);
}` Delete it if you want, still not working...

Comment: @webeno You are right, but I don't know how to be more specific and I'm a little bit nervous because it's working perfectly if I just copy and paste from w3schools :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `<script>` content into the `<body>` area was the solution

Answer (score 0):

i put your code on window.onload event

```
window.onload = function () {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName( "accordion" );

    for ( var j = 0; j < acc.length; j++ ) {
        acc[j].onclick = function () {
            this.classList.toggle( "active" );
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle( "show" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code but...still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The accordion functionality seemed to be working fine. I just added some css to make the text black and there it was!

```
div.panelacc.show p {
   color: black;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cyn9f0p0/)

It looks like your css on the `body` tag was making all your text white. Just need to override that.

Comment: That's weird...It's working perfectly on JSFiddle but it's not working in my computer...

Comment: Check browsers developer console, make sure you don't have any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Done! Nothing found...

Comment: Well something is stopping your Javascript from running. I would comment out all your js except what you need for the accordion and slowly uncomment peices to find out what's causing the problem.

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but putting the `<script>` part inside the `<body>` was the solution...